# Unable to remove spacing on content box using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove extra spacing on a product image that is causing the image to be off centre when looking on mobile. See attached.

I have used the following CSS but can remove spacing left and right of the image.

```
.product .image[class*=aspect-ratio-] .main-images-wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* height: 100%; */
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    /* background-color: #eaeaea; */
}
```

[image]

Comment: Container seems alright, can you check the box model on the img?

Comment: Make a fiddle snippet

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `object-fit: cover` because `contain` is preserving the image aspect ratio and it leaves the background empty; or you can add a `background-color` to the image and it will be filled with it.